# Type mismatch error in java

Tags: java, minecraft

I keep getting a type mismatch error for line 3 in the following code:

```
    try
    {
      int l = item.b(itemstack);
      String s = itemstack.l() + "@" + l;
      if (!hashset.contains(s))
      {
        list.add(itemstack);
        hashset.add(s);
      }
    }
```

I have no clue how to fix this (using the IDE's recommendation broke the code's functionality).

Here is the full class file I'm working on:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.text.FieldPosition;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;

public class TMIUtils
{
  public static final String CONFIG_FILENAME = "TooManyItems.txt";

  public static Minecraft getMinecraft()
  {
    try
    {
      Field field = Minecraft.class.getDeclaredField("a");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      return (Minecraft)field.get(null);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException illegalaccessexception)
    {
      illegalaccessexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException nosuchfieldexception)
    {
      nosuchfieldexception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static void loadPreferences(TMIConfig tmiconfig)
  {
    try
    {
      Map map = tmiconfig.getSettings();
      File file = new File(Minecraft.a("minecraft"), "TooManyItems.txt");
      if (file.exists())
      {
        BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String s;
        while ((s = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
        {
          String[] as = s.split(":", 2);
          if ((as.length > 1) && (map.containsKey(as[0])))
          {
            map.put(as[0], as[1]);
          }
        }
        bufferedreader.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmiconfig.getNumSaves(); i++)
        {
          tmiconfig.decodeState(i, (String)map.get("save" + (i + 1)));
        }
      }

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      System.out.println(exception);
    }
  }

  public static void savePreferences(TMIConfig tmiconfig)
  {
    try
    {
      Map map = tmiconfig.getSettings();
      File file = new File(Minecraft.a("minecraft"), "TooManyItems.txt");
      PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      String s;
      for (Iterator iterator = map.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); printwriter.println(s + ":" + (String)map.get(s)))
      {
        s = (String)iterator.next();
      }

      printwriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      System.out.println(exception);
    }
  }

  public static void loadItems(TMIConfig tmiconfig)
  {
    List list = tmiconfig.getItems();
    list.clear();
    sv[] aitem = sv.f;
    int i = aitem.length;
    int WiringID = 0;
    try
    {
      Class.forName("mod_RedPowerWiring");
      WiringID = ((Integer)ModLoader.getPrivateValue(mod_RedPowerWiring.class, null, "WiringID")).intValue();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
      sv item = aitem[j];
      if (item == null)
      {
        continue;
      }
      TMIConfig _tmp = tmiconfig;
      if (!TMIConfig.isItemIncluded(item.br))
      {
        continue;
      }
      HashSet hashset = new HashSet();

      short byte0 = (short)(tmiconfig.areDamageVariantsShown() ? 32767 : 0);
      for (int k = 0; k <= byte0; k++)
      {
        ul itemstack = new ul(item, item.d(), k);
        if ((k > 15) && (item.br != WiringID))
        {
          break;
        }
        try
        {
          int l = item.b(itemstack);
          String s = itemstack.l() + "@" + l;
          if (!hashset.contains(s))
          {
            list.add(itemstack);
            hashset.add(s);
          }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException nullpointerexception)
        {
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException indexoutofboundsexception)
        {
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void safeReportException(Exception exception) {
    try {
      SimpleDateFormat simpledateformat = new SimpleDateFormat(".yyyyMMdd.HHmmss");
      StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
      simpledateformat.format(new Date(), stringbuffer, new FieldPosition(1));
      String s = "tmi" + stringbuffer.toString() + ".txt";
      File file = new File(Minecraft.a("minecraft"), s);
      PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file));
      printwriter.print("[code]TMI Version: 1.7.2 2011-07-01\n");
      exception.printStackTrace(printwriter);
      printwriter.println("[/code]");
      printwriter.close();
      getMinecraft().v.a("Error written to " + s);
    }
    catch (Exception exception1)
    {
      System.out.println("Error during safeReportException:");
      exception1.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static String itemDisplayName(ul itemstack)
  {
    try
    {
      String s = wv.a().b(itemstack.l());
      if (!s.trim().equals(""))
      {
        return s;
      }
    } catch (NullPointerException nullpointerexception) {
    }
    return "Unnamed";
  }

  public static boolean isValidItem(ul itemstack)
  {
    return (itemstack == null) || ((itemstack.c >= 0) && (itemstack.c < sv.f.length) && (sv.f[itemstack.c] != null));
  }

  public static ul getValidItem(ul itemstack)
  {
    if (isValidItem(itemstack))
    {
      return itemstack;
    }

    return new ul(lr.at);
  }

  public static String getValidItemDisplayName(ul itemstack)
  {
    if (isValidItem(itemstack))
    {
      return itemDisplayName(itemstack);
    }

    return "Undefined Item";
  }

  public static void deleteHeldItem()
  {
    getMinecraft().h.as.b((ul)null);
  }

  public static ul getHeldItem()
  {
    return getMinecraft().h.as.j();
  }

  public static void giveStack(ul itemstack, TMIConfig tmiconfig)
  {
    giveStack(itemstack, tmiconfig, itemstack.a);
  }

  public static void giveStack(ul itemstack, TMIConfig tmiconfig, int i)
  {
    ul itemstack1 = copyStack(itemstack, i);
    Minecraft minecraft = getMinecraft();
    if (TMIConfig.isMultiplayer())
    {
      NumberFormat numberformat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
      numberformat.setGroupingUsed(false);
      MessageFormat messageformat = new MessageFormat((String)tmiconfig.getSettings().get("give-command"));
      messageformat.setFormatByArgumentIndex(1, numberformat);
      messageformat.setFormatByArgumentIndex(2, numberformat);
      messageformat.setFormatByArgumentIndex(3, numberformat);
      Object[] aobj = { minecraft.h.l, Integer.valueOf(itemstack1.c), Integer.valueOf(itemstack1.a), Integer.valueOf(itemstack1.i()) };

      minecraft.h.a(messageformat.format(aobj));
    }
    else {
      minecraft.h.as.a(itemstack1);
    }
  }

  public static ul copyStack(ul itemstack, int i)
  {
    if (itemstack == null)
    {
      return null;
    }

    itemstack.a += i;
    return itemstack.a(i);
  }

  public static ul copyStack(ul itemstack)
  {
    if (itemstack == null)
    {
      return null;
    }

    return copyStack(itemstack, itemstack.a);
  }

  public static void updateUnlimitedItems()
  {
    if ((TMIConfig.isMultiplayer()) || (!TMIConfig.getInstance().isEnabled()))
    {
      return;
    }
    ul[] aitemstack = getMinecraft().h.as.a;
    int i = aitemstack.length;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
      ul itemstack1 = aitemstack[j];
      if (itemstack1 == null)
      {
        continue;
      }
      if ((itemstack1.a < 0) || (itemstack1.a > 64))
      {
        itemstack1.a = 111;
      }
      if (itemstack1.i() >= 0)
        continue;
      setStackDamage(itemstack1, -32000);
    }

    ul itemstack = getHeldItem();
    if ((itemstack != null) && (itemstack.a > 64))
    {
      itemstack.a = -1;
    }
  }

  public static void setStackDamage(ul itemstack, int i)
  {
    try
    {
      Field[] afield = ul.class.getDeclaredFields();
      int j = afield.length;
      int k = 0;

      while (k < j)
      {
        Field field = afield[k];
        if (field.getName().equals("d"))
        {
          field.setAccessible(true);
          field.setInt(itemstack, i);
          break;
        }
        k++;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      System.out.println(exception);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You use this `ul` class in your code but there's no definition of it. What is it? Like `itemstack` in this is a `ul`: `String s = itemstack.l() + "@" + l;`

Comment: What does itemstack.b return?

Comment: You should post the relevant code (so all types involved in the error) and leave out all irrelevant stuff, so not everyone has to extract that themselves. That would make it much easier to find the problem and give you a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

which line is it?

```
int l = item.b(itemstack);
```

?

If yes, that means that `item.b(itemstack)` cannot be assigned to `int` and causes the error because there is a potential loss of precision. That would mean that `item.b(itemstack)` is probably `long`

Check what `item.b(itemstack)` returns. Then if it *does* return a `long`, change `l`'s type to `long`:

```
long l = item.b(itemstack);
```